# Why WPF are rendering Collapsed or Hidden Controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, render, cpu-usage

I am testing my WPF Application.i have a problem to performance on this project.

Why WPF are rendering Collapsed or Hidden Controls?

my CPU Usage is not change if i collapse or visible controls.

example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">
        <Button Content="visible" Margin="5" Padding="5,0,5,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="hidden" Margin="5" Padding="5,0,5,0" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button Content="collapsed" Margin="5" Padding="5,0,5,0" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="renderStack">
        <ProgressBar Height="30" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        <ProgressBar Height="30" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        <ProgressBar Height="30" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        <ProgressBar Height="30" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        <ProgressBar Height="30" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        <ProgressBar Height="30" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        <ProgressBar Height="30" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        <ProgressBar Height="30" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        <ProgressBar Height="30" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        <ProgressBar Height="30" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        <ProgressBar Height="30" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        <ProgressBar Height="30" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        renderStack.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        renderStack.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        renderStack.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `IsEnabled` to false as well? This should be more effective at stopping the items from using CPU. How many items are involved in your real-life case?

Comment: yes tested renderStack.IsEnabled = false; and not work... CPU usage not changed

Comment: IsEnabled does often not change the processing power of a control. (Depends on the implementation) If you really want to make the framework ignore your controls you should remove them from the tree and add them back if you need them.

Comment: yes if i remove control from StackPanel . cpu usage changed to low...
is it good idea?Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

i know this is old but just in case anyone comes looking. I have found that even tho the object is hidden more so with the progress bar when set to indeterminate will still take processor while hidden or collapsed as it is still rendering the animation. Try using .IsIndeterminate = False at the same time as hiding or collapsing it and you should see the cpu use drop.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the MSDN

> Elements where Visibility is not Visible do not participate in input
>   events (or commands), do not influence either the Measure or Arrange
>   passes of layout, are not in a tab sequence, and will not be reported
>   in hit testing.

maybe the problem is note the GUI itself. Are you executing any background operation?

Comment: no i'm not executing any background operation.i want to stop rendering a control in background operation.